# Exponential random numbers

Tags: matlab, statistics, octave, probability

I am using Matlab's `exprnd()` to generate random exponential numbers from an exponential distribution with a certain x.From what i understand this returns values using the distribution's probability density function which for a cerain lambda has max value of that lambda.

So for `exprnd(5)` i excpect values <=5.However this gives greater values than 5(up to 20+).What am i missing here? Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

What the input parameter is, is the mean value of what the exprnd() function's distribution would be. So you can still get values larger than 5.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the help document of `exprnd` in https://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/exprnd.html

> r = exprnd(mu) generates a random number from the exponential
>   distribution with mean mu.

For you case, `exprnd(5)` means that your mean value for generated random variables should be `5`, which doesn't mean `5` is the upper limit of random variables. For example:

```
>> exprnd(5,20,1)
ans =

    4.10770701
    0.60208519
    7.25872556
    0.05434071
    1.56567225
    1.25327626
    2.27920247
   13.76730426
    2.26669862
    8.16033821
    2.65390762
    2.59892165
    2.68864424
    2.20960785
    3.64418947
    0.00052336
    4.78444353
    0.70408921
    2.20180562
   19.10507978
```

When you have sufficiently large number of random variables, then the mean would approach `5`, i.e.,

```
>> mean(exprnd(5,1e5,1))
ans =  5.0052
```